# From a python embedded program, how do I get access to a an instance value?

Tags: python, embedded

Assume that I have the following c-program with embedded python:

```
const char *pyCode =
  "class Foo:\n"
  "  def __init__(self):\n"
  "    self.foo = 42\n"
  "  def set_foo(foo):\n"
  "    self.foo=foo\n"
  "\n"
  "foo=Foo()\n"
  ;

Py_Initialize();
PyObject* main_module = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
PyObject* main_dict = PyModule_GetDict(main_module);
PyRun_StringFlags(pyCode, Py_file_input, main_dict, main_dict, NULL);
PyObject *FooObj = PyDict_GetItemString(main_dict, "foo");
```

Now the C variable `FooObj` is a reference to the python instance `foo`. But how do I access the attributes of `FooObj` from C?

In particular, how can I get access to the PyObject 'foo.foo'?

And how can I from C call the member function foo.set_foo()?

Comment: Why are you embedding Python? There's scads of reasons why writing extension modules works better. (Many of them are enumerated in http://twistedmatrix.com/users/glyph/rant/extendit.html)

Comment: Because we are writing a large complex C++ application with a Qt front that controls a homebuilt piece of hardware with tens of electronic cards, tens of PLC's, pumps, robotic arms, cameras, tens of threads, etc. Python is used for gluing and for scripting this complex system. Turning it inside out (C++ inside and Python outside) is not in our scope for the foreseeable future. But thanks for the suggestion. :-)

Comment: Nothing about that complexity really suggests why embedding would be a better choice, and the use of Python as "glue" strongly suggests that extending could be an especially better fit. Extending Python does not imply that a larger amount of your code is written in Python, but it does give you easier access to tooling like Cython and to the wealth of existing Python software out there when writing the core Python-C++ glue and the high-level scripts. If anything, extending manages to keep Python *out* of the places you don't want it, the more libraryish sections of your code.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.python.org/c-api/ is your friend.

Attributes are read with [`PyObject_GetAttr()`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html#PyObject_GetAttr) or [`PyObject_GetAttrString()`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html#PyObject_GetAttrString), methods are called with [`PyObject_CallMethod()`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html#PyObject_CallMethod).

Comment: No, it is a reference to the attribute. If you change the attribute, the object holds a reference to the new value, while your before retrieved `PyObject *` refers to the old value. Besides, you must take care about reference counting and reference ownership.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that after I read the manual. Still not clear why you can get a reference to a variable inside a dictionary, but not to a instance variable. But in practice it really doesn't matter.

Comment: To both the same applies. If you get a reference to an entry in the dict and then replace it in the dict, you still reference the old entry.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [object protocol](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html) functions. `PyObject_GetAttr` family is an attribute access (e.g. `PyObject_GetAttrString(FooObj, "foo")`, `PyObject_Call` family is a function call (e.g. `PyObject_CallMethod(FooObj, "set_obj", "(O)", some_other_object)`).